# Alignment within align portion of subequations

Tags: align, amsmath, subequations

I am trying to align equations within an `align` environment. Below is a MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    3 & : & A = X \\
    2 & : & A = Y \\
    2 & : & A = XY
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

In this example, the 'A's are out of alignment because (I assume) the columns are right justified.  I'd really like to use aligned commands, something along the lines of

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}{rcl}
    3 & : & A = X \\
    2 & : & A = Y \\
    1 & : & A = XY
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Sorry for my simple example, tried to make MWE as small as possible.

Comment: Use `alignat` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you obtain is normal: when you have several alignment points, all alignment columns, but the first, have to be introduced by an ampersand, and inside this column, the alignment point is specified by a second ampersand, so that  two alignment points require `3` ampersands. If the  last one  is missing, it is implicitly added at the end of each row, so that the second column is right aligned.

The correct code is this:

```
      \begin{align}
    3 & : & &A = X \\
    2 & : & &A = Y \\
    2 & : & &A = XY
  \end{align}
```

or maybe, if you want to ensure the `=` are aligned, use `3 & : & A & = X`, &c.

Comment: That solved the problem perfectly.  Thank you for the fast response!